# How can I find location of a private IP address?

Tags: python, ip-address, python-ipaddress

Basically, I have created a program that finds the location of a public IP address, but out of curiosity is there any way to get my exact location with my private IP address.

```
import pygeoip
import requests
my_ip_addr = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text

gip = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoLiteCity.dat')
res = gip.record_by_addr(my_ip_addr)

for key, val in res.items():
    print(f'{key} : {val}')
```

Answer (score 1):

A private address is, as the name suggests, **private**. It only exists within your local network.

From your program, only your public address can be seen, which is the address of your router. [Here](https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private) are more details about the differences.

So no, you cannot find your location using your private address.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. A private IP is PRIVATE. To get location or other insights such as network level information, you must provide the PUBLIC IP address to a IP geolocation service.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to geolocate using private IP address.

Let's consider the real world scenario. The 10.0.0.1 is a private IP address. Network administrator in location X assigned 10.0.0.1 to one machine in LAN A. Another network administrator in location Y assigned 10.0.0.1 to another machine in LAN B. Therefore, there is no unique geolocation information can be assigned to private IP address.